Binding issue with StepInput in SAP Fiori using CAP as the backend
I'm working on a project using SAP CAP for the backend and Fiori Elements for the frontend. I’m facing a specific issue with the binding of a StepInput in an XML view. When I try to modify the value, it doesn’t seem to update properly in the model or reflect correctly in the StepInput after being processed.
My setup:

Backend: SAP CAP (Node.js)
Frontend: SAP Fiori with SAPUI5 (XML view)
Model: OData V4 (generated by CAP)

The issue:
The StepInput displays the initial value correctly, and I can retrieve the modifications made in the UI. When I modify the value, I trigger an API call to perform a calculation using the modified value and other data. The API correctly returns the calculated result, but this updated value is not reflected in the StepInput.
What I’ve tried:

Verified the binding in the XML view.
Checked that the change event correctly triggers the calculation and updates the model.
Ensured that the API returns the correct value and that it’s assigned back to the model.
Verified that the OData service exposes the necessary metadata for the field.

GitHub repository:
I have created a public repository with a minimal example to reproduce the issue:
GitHub Repository
Thank for the help
